# How to mock the Data Stax Row object[com.datastax.driver.core.Row;] - Unit Test

Tags: cassandra, junit4, powermockito, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

Please find the below code for the DAO & Entity Object and Accessor

```
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class Employee {

    @PartitionKey
    @Column(name = "empname")
    private String empname;

    @ClusteringColumn(0)
    @Column(name = "country")
    private String country;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;

}
```

Accessor:

```
@Accessor
public interface EmployeeAccessor { 

@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT empname FROM EMPLOYEE ")
ResultSet getAllEmployeeName();

}

}
```

DAO getAllEmployeeNames returns a List which are employee names
and it will be sorted in ascending order.
DAO

```
public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO {

    private EmployeeAccessor employeeAccessor;

        @PostConstruct
        public void init() {
            employeeAccessor = datastaxCassandraTemplate.getAccessor(EmployeeAccessor.class);
            }


    @Override
        public List<String> getAllEmployeeNames() {
            List<Row> names = employeeAccessor.getAllEmployeeName().all();
            List<String> empnames = names.stream()
                    .map(name -> name.getString("empname")).collect(Collectors.toList());
            empnames.sort(naturalOrder()); //sorted
            return empnames;
        }

    }
```

JUnit Test(mockito):

I am not able to mock the List[datastax row]. How to mock and returns a list of rows with values "foo" and "bar".Please help me in unit test this.

```
@Category(UnitTest.class)
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class EmployeeDAOImplUnitTest {  

    @Mock
    private ResultSet resultSet;

    @Mock
    private EmployeeAccessor empAccessor;

    //here is the problem....how to mock the List<Row> Object -->  com.datastax.driver.core.Row (interface)
    //this code will result in compilation error as we are mapping a List<Row> to the ArrayList<String>
    //how to mock the List<Row> with a list of String row object
    private List<Row> unSortedTemplateNames = new ArrayList() {
            {
                add("foo");
                add("bar");
            }
        };

        //this is a test case to check if the results are sorted or not
        //mock the accessor and send rows as "foo" & "bar"
        //after calling the dao , the first element must be "bar" and not "foo"
        @Test
            public void shouldReturnSorted_getAllTemplateNames() {
                when(empAccessor.getAllEmployeeName()).thenReturn(resultSet);
                when(resultSet.all()).thenReturn(unSortedTemplateNames); //how to mock the List<Row> object ???
                //i am testing if the results are sorted, first element should not be foo
                assertThat(countryTemplates.get(0), is("bar"));
            }   

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow!  This is overly complex, hard to follow, and not an ideal way to write unit tests.

Using PowerMock(ito) along with "static" references in your own code is not recommended and is a sure sign of a code smells.

First, I am not sure why you decided to use a static reference (e.g. `EmployeeAccessor.getAllEmployeeName().all();` inside the `EmployeeDAOImpl` class, `getAllEmployeeNames()` method) instead of using the instance variable (i.e. `empAccessor`), which is more conducive to actual "unit testing"?

The `EmployeeAccessor`, `getAllEmployeeName()` "interface" method is not static (clearly).  However, seemingly, whatever this (`datastaxCassandraTemplate.getAccessor(EmployeeAccessor.class);`) generates makes it so (really?), which then requires the use of *PowerMock(ito)*, o.O

Frameworks like *PowerMock*, and extensions of (i.e. "*PowerMockito*"), were meant to test and mock code used by your application (unfortunately, but necessarily so) where this "other" code makes use of statics, Singletons, private methods and so on.  This anti-pattern really ought not be followed in your own application design.

Second, it is not really apparent what the "*Subject Under Test*" (SUT) is in your test case.  You implemented a test class (i.e. `EmployeeDAOImplTest`) for, supposedly, your `EmployeeDAOImpl` class (the actual "SUT"), but inside your test case (i.e. `shouldReturnSorted_getAllTemplateNames()`), you are calling... `countryLocalizationDAOImpl.getAllTemplateNames();` thus testing the `CountryLocalizationDAOImpl` class (??), which is not the "SUT" of the `EmployeeDAOImplTest` class.

Additionally, it is not apparent that the `EmployeeDAOImpl` even uses a `CountryLocalizationDAO` instance (assuming an interface here as well), and if it does, then it is certainly something that should be "mocked" when the `EmployeeDAOImpl` "interacts" with instances of `CountryLocalizationDAO`, particularly in the context of a unit test.  The only correlation between the `EmployeeDAO` and `CountryLocalizationDAO` is that the `Employee` has a `country` field.

There are a few other problems with your design/setup as well, but anyway.

Here are a few suggestions...

First, let's test what your `EmployeeDAOImplTest` is meant to test... `EmployeeDAO.getAllEmployeeNames()` in a sorted fashion.  This in turn may give you ideas of how to test your "`CountryLocalizationDAO`, `getAllTemplateNames()` method perhaps (if it even makes sense, i.e. `getAllTemplateNames()` is in fact dependent on an `Employee's` `country`, when `Employees` are ordered by name (i.e. "`empname`" and accessed via `EmployeeAccessor`).

```
public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO {

    private final EmployeeAccessor employeeAccessor;

    // where does the DataStaxCassandraTemplate reference come from?!
    private DataStaxCassadraTemplate datastaxCassandraTemplate = ...;

    public EmployeeDAOImpl() {
        this(datastaxCassandraTemplate.getAccessor(EmployeeAccessor.class));
    }

    public EmployeeDAOImpl(EmployeeAccessor employeeAccessor) {
        this.employeeAccessor = employeeAccessor;
    }

    protected EmployeeAccessor getEmployeeAccessor() {
        return this.empAccessor;
    }

    public List<String> getAllEployeeNames() {
        List<Row> nameRows = getEmployeeAccessor().getAllEmployeeName().all();
        ...
    }
}
```

Then in your test class...

```
public class EmployeeDAOImplUnitTest { 

    @Mock
    private EmployeeAccessor mockEmployeeAccessor;

    // SUT
    private EmployeeDAO employeeDao;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        employeeDao = new EmployeeDAOImpl(mockEmployeeAccessor);
    }

    protected ResultSet mockResultSet(Row... rows) {
        ResultSet mockResultSet = mock(ResultSet.class);
        when(mockResultSet.all()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(rows));
        return mockResultSet;
    }

    protected Row mockRow(String employeeName) {
        Row mockRow = mock(Row.class, employeeName);
        when(mockRow.getString(eq("empname")).thenReturn(employeeName);
        return mockRow;
    }

    @Test
    public void getAllEmployeeNamesReturnsSortListOfNames() {
        when(mockEmployeeAccessor.getAllEmployeeName())
            .thenReturn(mockResultSet(mockRow("jonDoe"), mockRow("janeDoe")));

        assertThat(employeeDao.getAllEmployeeNames())
            .contains("janeDoe", "jonDoe");

        verify(mockEmployeeAccessor, times(1)).getAllEmployeeName();
    }
}
```

Now, you can apply similar techniques if in fact there is an actual correlation between `Employees` and `CountryLocalizationDAO` via the `EmployeeAccessor`.

Hope this helps get you on a better track!

-j

Comment: Thanks John. Corrected the code i.e.) employeeAccessor.getAllEmployeeName().all(). After following what you have told,  I am getting the following error. org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:@ this line of code. when(mockRow.getString(eq("empname")).thenReturn(employeeName);

Comment: countryLocalizationDAOImpl.getAllTemplateNames is removed. code cleaned. some copy paste error.

Comment: HI Raghu- for clarification, you have everything working now?  Disclaimer, all the code I wrote in my answer, I wrote from memory and did not compile/test, so... sorry if there were typos.  I tried to be exact.

Comment: Thanks john, its working now. This statement should be outside the mockResultSet. when(mockResultSet.all()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(rows)); This statement should be outside of the mockRow.when(mockRow.getString(eq("empname")).thenReturn(employeeName); You have solved my problem. I have accepted the answer. Your are awesome.

Comment: Just for the interest of others, this is how the problem is solved. full credit to john blum. public void test_sortingOfTemplateNames() {
       Row row1 = mockRow("raghuraman");
       Row row2 = mockRow("johnblum");
       Row row3 = mockRow("arunkumar");
       List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<>();
       rows.add(row1);
       rows.add(row2);
       rows.add(row3);

Comment: Continuation....ResultSet rs = mockResultSet(row1,row2,row3);
       when(employeeDao.getAllEmployeeNames())
           .thenReturn(rs);
       when(rs.all()).thenReturn(rows);
       when(row1.getString(eq("empname"))).thenReturn("raghuraman");
       when(row2.getString(eq("empname"))).thenReturn("johnblum");
       when(row3.getString(eq("empname"))).thenReturn("arunkumar");
       List<String> empNames = employeeDao.getAllEmployeeNames();
       assertTrue(empNames.get(0).equals("arunkumar"));
   }

Comment: protected ResultSet mockResultSet(Row... rows) {
        ResultSet mockResultSet = mock(ResultSet.class);
        return mockResultSet;
    }

    protected Row mockRow(String templateName) {
        Row mockRow = mock(Row.class, templateName);
        return mockRow;
    }

Comment: Writing the code just from memory. Unbelievable. Salute.

Comment: What is the use of the parameter Rows... in this method, 

ResultSet mockResultSet(Row... rows) { ResultSet mockResultSet = mock(ResultSet.class); return mockResultSet; }
I do not see any need, secondly, I think the test is skewed to work, I cannot see any relationship between the generated records and the expected mock result.

The rows have no reference to the other fields apart from the name column, which makes this test look seemingly outrightly obnoxious to upvote.